# Find $\text{Cov}(N_{1}(t),N_{2}(t))$

Tags: stochastic-processes, covariance, poisson-process

Let $\{M_{i}(t), t \geq 0\}$, $i=1,2,3$ be independent Poisson processes with respect rates $\lambda_{i}$, $i=1,2,3$ and set $$N_{1}(t)=M_{1}(t)+M_{2}(t), \quad N_{2}(t)=M_{2}(t)+M_{3}(t)$$
The stochastic process $\{(N_{1}(t), N_{2}(t)),t \geq 0\}$ is called a bivariate Poisson process.

Find $\text{Cov}(N_{1}(t),N_{2}(t))$.

Hello, I am trying to solve this problem and I did the following
\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}[N_{1}(t), N_{2}(t)] &= \text{Cov}[M_{1}(t)+M_{2}(t), M_{2}(t)+M_{3}(t)]\\
&= \text{Cov}[M_{2}(t), M_{2}(t)] \quad (\text{By independence})\\
&= \text{Var}(M_{2}(t)).
\end{align*}
But I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

We can compute this directly using the identity
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathbb E[XY] - \mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y]
$$
and the fact that for independent random variables with finite expectation,
$$
\mathbb E[XY] = \mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y]:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Cov}(N_1(t),N_2(t)) &= \mathbb E[(M_1(t)+M_2(t))(M_2(t)+M_3(t))] - \mathbb E[M_1(t)+M_2(t)]\mathbb E[M_1(t)+M_2(t)]\\
&= \mathbb E[M_1(t)M_2(t) + M_2(t)^2+M_1(t)M_3(t)+M_2(t)M_3(t)] - (\lambda_1+\lambda_2)(\lambda_2+\lambda_3)\\
&= \lambda_1\lambda_2+\lambda_2^2+\lambda_1\lambda_3 + \lambda_2\lambda_3 - (\lambda_1\lambda_2+\lambda_2^2+\lambda_2+\lambda_1\lambda_3+\lambda_2\lambda_3)\\
&= \lambda_2.
\end{align}